# Understanding dummy trap? Python3

Tags: python-3.x, function, get, dummy-variable

I would like to clarify the true understanding of dummy trap. So basically, it removes redundancy when it is obvious that the value for that particular column has to be either one of the values. Am I right? Taking an example below

**Originally**

```
 Survived | Pclass | Sex | Age | Fare | Embarked | FamilySize
```

After applying getdummy function, the "Sex" column disappears from the dataframe.

**Result**

```
  Survived | Pclass | Age | Fare | Embarked | FamilySize
```

I just would like to check my understanding. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`pandas.get_dummies()` **Convert categorical variable into dummy/indicator variables**

Since **Sex** is a categorical variable it is changed to indicator variables.

Reference for Syntax & Examples [Official_Link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)

Reference for Understanding the Dummy function[Dummy](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-dummys-guide-to-creating-dummy-variables-f21faddb1d40)